# Sample raster cell value at coordinates?

Tags: python, gdal, gmt

I have many rasters in ESRI ASCII format (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Esri_ASCII_raster_format/009t0000000z000000/).

I need to extract cell values at given locations / coordinates. Can anyone suggest a python package to achieve this? I suspect there may be something in gdal tools but I have been unable to find anything so far.

I am looking for similar functionality to GMT grdtrack, with which you can pass a table of coordinates and retrieve the cell value. 
http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/doc/5.1.0/grdtrack.html

However I was hoping / wondering if this is possible in python as my previous and later stages of my analysis are all in python.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can do this with GDAL. Provided that you have the coordinate where you want to sample your raster in the same projection you can do something like this:

```
from osgeo import gdal

def world2Pixel(gt, x, y):
  ulX = gt[0]
  ulY = gt[3]
  xDist = gt[1]
  yDist = gt[5]
  rtnX = gt[2]
  rtnY = gt[4]
  pixel = int((x - ulX) / xDist)
  line = int((ulY - y) / yDist)
  return (pixel, line)

dataset = gdal.Open(filename)
gt = dataset.GetGeoTransform()

pixel, line = world2Pixel(gt, x, y)

band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
value = band.ReadAsArray(pixel, line, 1, 1)[0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks that works great!
 Apologies to all for posting an ambiguous question: my original solution used GMT grdtrack. 
"grdtrack $table_of_XY -G$grid -Ql > $values_out"

Comment: There seems to be an error in the answer, please verify if this:
`line = int((ulY - y) / xDist)` 
should be this: 
`line = int((ulY - y) / yDist)`

Comment: It should actually be: `line = int((ulY - y) / - yDist)`, since gt[5] is returned as a negative value (as it reads from here https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html).  Sorry for the double update. 

Actually, I saw that here: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html they use the same world2Pixel function in the incorrect form.